# How to connect redis with django project?

Tags: python, django, redis, django-channels

As i'am new to channels and redis i don't able to fix the issue. The issue is when i tried testing the redis whether it is working or not? it passes the test. But when i run the project i cant able to see the index page. I have explained the issue in detail below. Someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Installed packages
  python 3.4
  django 1.10
  redis 2.10
  channels
  sockets

When i test redis it works fine. Attached the screenshot below.

[Testing Redis Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmNJI.jpg)

When i run the project i got the below error message in the terminal. Attached the screenshot below.

[python manage.py runserver 8000 [screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0S2y.jpg)

I have attached my code blocks below.

## routing.py

```
from channels.routing import route
from chat_room.consumers import ws_connect, ws_disconnect


channel_routing = [
    route('websocket.connect', ws_connect),
    route('websocket.disconnect', ws_disconnect),
]
```

## settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'channels',
'chat_room',
]

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('localhost', 6379)],
        },
        'ROUTING': 'chat_application.routing.channel_routing',
    }
}
```

## consumers.py

```
from channels import Group


def ws_connect(message):
    Group('users').add(message.reply_channel)


def ws_disconnect(message):
    Group('users').discard(message.reply_channel)
```

## index.html

```
....some code....
<script>
    var socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/users/');
    socket.onopen = function open() {
      console.log('WebSockets connection created.');
    };
    socket.onmessage = function message(event) {
      var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      var username = encodeURI(data['username']);
      var user = $('li').filter(function () {
        return $(this).data('username') == username;
      });
      if (data['is_logged_in']) {
        user.html(username + ': Online');
      }
      else {
        user.html(username + ': Offline');
      }
    };
    if (socket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
      socket.onopen();
    }
</script>
......
```

Comment: Please include error `traceback` in `code block` format

Comment: I have already attached the screenshot of the traceback error in the name of (python manage.py runserver 8000 [screenshot]). Please check that screenshot